# Android Access Activity Methods From Non-Activity Class

Tags: java, android

This is the method I want to access from the Activity class (ActivityName):

```
public MediaPlayer getBlipComp() {
    return blipComp;
}
```

**EDIT**

In the activity class

```
public SingleGameActivity getSingleGameActivity() {
    return this;
}
```

This is working fine in my SurfaceView class:

```
SingleGameActivity myActivity = ((SingleGameActivity)getContext()).getSingleGameActivity();


// Later in the code 
myActivity.getBlipStart().start();
```

But when I pass the reference variable to the ball (normal)-class it doesn't work:

```
ball = new Ball(myActivity, box.getCenterX(), box.getCenterY(), currentLvl,
            Color.GREEN);
```

Ball-class

```
public Ball(SingleGameActivity activity, int xPos, int yPos, int level,
        int color) {
    myActivity = activity;
```

**THIS METHOD CAN NOT BE CALLED FROM THE BALL CLASS, WHY? SOLUTION?**

```
myActivity.getBlipPlay().start();
```

Comment: you can pass activity instance to other class where you want to access

Comment: try using a static function or pass the context via the class constructor...

Comment: @Pankaj Could you post an answer with an example, please? I don't get it, sorry... Neither do I get your comment sabeersas. (I'm new to Android and Java programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the ActivityName instance into the constructor of NormalClass like this:

```
public class NormalClass {
   private ActivityName activity;

   public NormalClass(ActivityName activity){
      this.activity = activity;
   }

   public void doSomething()
   {
      activity.getBlipComp();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was what I was searching for! However it doesn't work yet as I'm calling the NormalClass-constructor from a SurfaceView class. Therefore I need an ActivityName reference in my SurfaceView class that I can pass to the NormalClass constructor. How do I do that?

Comment: Pass it to the SurfaceView class so that it can pass it on.  You can use a `setter` method if passing it to the constructor isn't an option.

Comment: It appears that you do that in your code like this:`((ActivityName) getContext())`. So try this: `ActivityName activity = ((ActivityName) getContext()); NormalClass normalClass = new NormalClass(activity)`

Comment: I have tried both your advices, but sadly none of them works in my Ball class (AKA Normal-class). However it works fine in the SurfaceView-class. Why? I edited my question to give you more details.

Answer (score -1):

this line: 
    ActivityName name = new ActivityName(); 
actually creates a new Activity show. 
thats not what you want.

You have to options to do this: 
1. you pass the Activity show to the "normal class" and keep it as a field:

```
public class NormalClass {
private Activity myActivity;
```

and use it as you want.

2.do the same only in the activity class.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

public static Activity myActivity;
```

and int the constructor assign "MyActivity.myActivity = this;"

and than use  a static method like so to use your activity:

```
public static MediaPlayer getBlipComp(){
   return myActivity.getBlipComp();
}
```

and than use this method like so:

```
MyActivity.getBlipComp();
```

Have Fun!

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! However, if possible, I'd like to do it without making the methods static. I'd like to learn how to do that! :)

Comment: well your not making the method static, your making ANOTHER method just like it, only static. that static will trigger the non-static. if you dont want it to be static use the first option I gave you.

Comment: From method number 2 I get this error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field myActivity". However when I tried option 1 I need an activity reference in my SurfaceView class (from where I call the "normal class's" constructor). DO you know how to do that?

Comment: Thats right the field in method 2 should be static and be assigned like so : MyActivity.myAvtivity= this;" sorry. for the other thing (method 1) , when you construct the "Normal Class" add to the constructor a parameter: "public Normal(....your other stuf... , MyActivity myActivity)"  than in the constructor add this line : "this.myActivity = myActivity;"  and pass the activity when contructing the Normal Class (as a guess it will be "this" ). dont forget to accept my answer! :)

Comment: -1 for asking the op to accept your answer.  Don't do that, especially at this stage.

Comment: @Fashizel Your advice didn't work neither, I'm sorry. But please see the edited question I changed! :)

Comment: Too bad.  But the accepted answer is exactly what i offerd. Its ok ;)